# F# find in list of records the records with same id and add up their values

Tags: list, f#, find

Iam an F# newbie, I have following starting point:

```
type aB = { ID: int; Slide: list<string * int> }

// examples of aB's
let aB1 = { ID = 1; Slide = [("-10%",-20); ("0%",0); ("10%",20)] }
let aB2 = { ID = 2; Slide = [("-10%",6); ("0%",0); ("10%",3)] }
let correctoraB2 = {ID = 2; Slide = [("-10%", -2); ("0%", 0); ("10%", -1)]  }

// Now we bunch the aB`s in a list together 
let bunchedABRaw = [aB1; aB2; correctoraB2]
```

This list can now become quite long, in this list, I need now to first identify all the aB's with identical ID's, then I want to net out their slides, so that a new list results

`let bunchedABReduced = [aB1; aB2New]`, where

`aB2New = { ID = 2; Slide = [("-10%",4); ("0%",0); ("10%",2)]  }`

I am reading through the F# library on msdn but so far I don't know yet how to solve the problem, would be very happy for code proposition.

Thanks a lot
Martin

Comment: Are there always 3 tuples in the slide of an aB? Or can this list be any length?

Comment: Define "net out their slides"? I can't figure out from your question which operation you're applying.

Comment: @Onorio: the operation is adding up the values

Comment: @gjvdkamp: there can be any number of tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK working my way through this when I have a minute.

Here's the first part where you can merge the slides of two aB's:

```
// this function can merge two slides
let mergeSlides l1 l2 = 
    List.zip l1 l2
    |> List.map (fun ((a1, b1), (a2,b2)) -> (a1, b1+b2))

// see what it does
mergeSlides aB2.Slide correctoraB2.Slide
```

This bit groups all the aB's with the same Id:

```
let grp = bunchedABRaw
|> Seq.groupBy (fun a -> a.ID)
```

And now we can use mergeSlides as a folding function, that we use fold over each sequence of Ab's with the same Id to make the netted aB.

So here's the whole thing:

```
let mergeSlides l1 l2 = 
    List.zip l1 l2
    |> List.map (fun ((a1, b1), (a2,b2)) -> (a1, b1+b2))

let net =
    bunchedABRaw
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun a -> a.ID)
    |> Seq.map (fun (i, s) -> (i, s |> Seq.map (fun a -> a.Slide))) // strip away the slides
    |> Seq.map (fun (i, s) -> (i, List.ofSeq s)) // turn seq<slide> into list<slide>
    |> Seq.map (fun (i, l) -> (i, List.fold mergeSlides l.Head l.Tail)) // so we can use HEad and Tail
    |> Seq.map (fun (i, l) -> {ID=i;Slide=l}) // and Project into aB
    |> List.ofSeq // and then List
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Good approach @gjvdkamp.  I always try to fix things in one step when they work much better when taken piecewise the way you did that.

Comment: @gjvdkamp thanks a lot very understandable, waiting for the last bit;-), its not that straightforward to get into the way of F# thinking but very cool when you start understanding..

Comment: ok done! Be careful with Seq.groupBy though, becasue it needs to iterate over the whole sequence before it can continue, so it can use up a lot of memory for large sequences. In that case you want to use fold and tread a Dictionary along your original List.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set up a dictionary where the keys will be the IDs you encounter and the values will be a "netted" aB type for that ID.

Then run a fold* on the list using the dictionary as your state and have the function you fold across the list accumulate the items in the dictionary by ID ("netting" them as you go).

After that you can put all the dictionary's values into a return list.

If you can't "net" them as you go then you could store a list of items as values instead of a single "netted" value and then do the netting after the fold finishes.

*fold http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx

EDIT: Made some things clearer